# Books and tutorials about jQuery and Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am trying to learn jQuery in Rails 3 context. (I have no experience with other JS libraries). A couple hours Googling didn't turn up much. The only book I can find is Practical Rails with jQuery Projects.

Could you recommend books, tutorials etc. that cover more than just up and running jQuery in Rails?

(I know some people will suggest to learn jQuery as a separate topic, and I am doing that. But integrate it to Rails brings unique challenges).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Hi Simone, could you please advice on which don't ask rule I violated, and what would be a good way to ask about it? Integrating jQuery with Rails 3 is a technical problem I have and I need to learn more about it in a systematic way.

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.  If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: Thanks. I only ask for references on a technical topic, but may be too broad for SO.

Comment: I found another book reference: [Ajax on Rails](http://www.flipkart.com/ajax-rails-364-pages/p/itmdyusdprw5akud?pid=9788184042610&ref=9298d228-b38b-4fcf-9290-9252214543b9&srno=s_3&otracker=from-search&query=rails%20+%20ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some good stuff about doing ajaxy stuff with rails here: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Apart from that there's not much that is rails specific.